# Export the part or doc lists to XLS or XLSX with the hyperlink in object number to their info page

Tags: ptc-windchill

In Windchill 10.1, In the folder view of any container, when you click on the name field of any document, it takes you to the details page of the document. So the names are actually hyperlinks to the details of the document.
My requirement is to export these hyperlinks from windchill into excel sheet using export list to xlsx from actions menu in the folder page
Please reply if any one had an idea of how this can be done as i need to submit it with a solution in 2 days